# Use function in angular-editable to return html instead of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Im using angular to build a web application. Since I need a table to be editable i decided to use angular-xeditable. I ran into the following problem.

Inside my Controller I got a function:

```
function xyz(param){
    return "<span>"+param+"</span>";
}
```

In the html view file which contains the form and table the function is called inside a editable field:

```
<td>
    <span editable-select="test.element" e-name="element" e-ng-click="onElementChange()" e-form="tableform" e-multiple e-ng-options="element.id as element.name for element in elements">
        {{ xyz(param) }}
    </span>
</td>
```

If I use it like that, unfortunately inside the table no span is inserted but a text containing the html code as well: "paramvalue"

Whats going wrong. Am I missing something? Do I need to en/decode the return value in any way? Did not find any possible solutions.

Would be thankful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead use angular directive "ng-bind-html" to insert/bind string to HTML. Angular provides directive for this purpose. See this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

```
<div ng-bind-html="xyz(param)"></div>
```

Assuming function xyz is available on controller scope.

Comment: should have found that on my own.. You made my day. Thank u

Comment: I am glad it helped you. If this is the answer to your problem, then accept it as an answer so that it can help others too.